# How to add 232.83GB of unallocated space to a mounted partition using GParted?

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, gparted, crunchbang

I have the following partition layout:

[image: partition]

I am wanting to move this 232.86GB of unallocated space to an already-mounted partition (/dev/sda1) using GParted.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible with a live distro and GParted!

1. Resize partition 2 to include the unallocated space in front of it.
2. Resize partition 6 to include the unallocated space in front of it.
3. Apply the changes! This probably going to take a long while.
4. Reboot!

Unfortunately a software, hardware or power failure during step 3 can leave the file system in an inconsistent state. It would be wise to create a backup beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

It's already on /dev/sda, but I assume you mean add it to /dev/sda6 to be with the rest of your space.

Though partitions can often be extended w/o reformatting, AFAIK they can't be prepended w/o reformatting.  If you were using LVM you could add that space to your volume, but unfortunately that's not the case here.

The short answer is you can't do this with gparted.

The next shortest answer is that the cleanest way to do this is to copy your data off and reformat the whole drive together.

You *might* be able to format the empty space with LVM, copy your current setup over to the new drive, rerun grub to load things from your new drive, boot from there, reformat your old space to LVM and attach it to your shiny new space and everything would look like one big contiguous disk... assuming you can fit your current setup into the smaller partition.

It's not exactly what you want, but the simplest solution you have is to format the empty space and them mount it where you need space.  Say, for example, you have 200gigs of music and it's eating up your free space:

Format empty space into sda1. 
mount /dev/sda1 into /mnt/newmusic.
move /home/lazy/music/* to /mnt/newmusic.
unmount /mnt/newmusic.
mount /dev/sda1 to /home/lazy/music.

add line for this mount to /etc/fstab to it's there when you reboot.

It won't be contiguous space, but it may be able to save you a lot of headache.